# Does this variable have an upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $x$ be a positive scalar variable. Its time derivative satisfies
$$|\dot{x}(t)|\le \exp\left\{-\int_{0}^t\frac{1}{x(\tau)}\mathrm{d} \tau\right\}$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the absolute value.
From the above inequality, can we say $x(t)$ with $t\in[0,+\infty)$ has a finite upper bound? No need to compute an exact upper bound. It is sufficient to show there exists a finite upper bound. I know if $|\dot{x}(t)|\le \exp\left\{-kt\right\}$, then $x(t)=\int_{0}^t \dot{x} \mathrm{d}\tau$ will have an upper bound $1/k$.

Comment: @WillieWong: you could write the answer you wrote at mathoverflow.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Thanks for the comment. I have posted an answer below to refer to the answer given in mathoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved in [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106594/does-this-variable-have-an-upper-bound).